# Таймер обратного отсчета на Java

Tags: java, таймер

Надо сделать таймер вида HH:MM:SS  на Java обратного отсчета по такому принципу действия:

1. Пользователь вводит длительность работы таймера (в секундах);
2. После нажатия кнопки таймер начинает обратный отсчет, отображается его работа;
3. Когда время истекает, таймер выводит надпись "TIME OVER";

Подскажите реализацию данного таймера.

Ниже прикрепляю пример:
[image: пример работы таймера]

Comment: Покажите ваши наработки, в противном случае это будет работа за вас, чем тут не занимаются.

Answer (score 1):

```
//start thread
() -> {
     updateBar(timeExpired)
     if (timeExpired == 0)
         scheduler.cancel(true); //cancel tread
         scheduler = null;
}, 1000, 1000); //schedule at fixed rate
```

Думаю Вы сможете описать дальнейшую логику.